# Classify items using DROOLS

Tags: java, classification, drools

I'd like to build a classificator machine of items, creating rules and using weight. There could be no clear details to define an item, just the high score. 
An example.

```
If item A has x part then A.set(Category.A, 5) //weigth 5 
If item A has y part then A.set(Category.B,3) //weigth 3 
If item A has z part then A.set(Category.B,2) //weigth 2 
...
```

After all the rules executed, you have an score of each category, so finally item A is Category whatever.

Is this possible using DROOLS? any example of this? 
Many thanks.

---

Adding more info as required:
I want to classify news (as example).

```
If NewsA has in title "won" then NewsA is likely SportNews as 20%
If NewsA is writen by MisterX then NewsA is likely InternationalNews as 60%
If NewsA has more than 2 times word "football" then NewsA is likely SportNews as 50%
```

So, one news like that:

> **Barcelona won yesterday**
>  bla, bla, bla... football, bla,... football, bla, bla, bla ...football...
>  *written by MisterX*

This news will be classified as SportNews because 20+50 is more than 60 of InternationalNews category. I want to implement something like that in doors, with multiple rules and weight.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should work for you. You'll have to provide more info for a more detailed example.

```
rule "category for X part"
when
  $itemA: A( hasXPart() )
then
  modify(itemA){ category( Category.A, 5) };
end
```

Comment: itemA => $itemA on the RHS. The semicolon is not required.

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of what I've called "classification problem" in my collection of Rule Design Patterns. Details vary, but the first issue is to separate the (usually) multidimensional space of attributes in a way so that exactly one rule fires *or, for more complex situations* to design the rules in a way where there is one set of rules investigating one related group of attributes.

Care must be taken if rules have to be applied according to some ranking.

But, as Andy wrote, there's not enough information in this post for a serious discussion.

**Later**
Indeed. Reading that section in https://engage.redhat.com/forms/rule-design-patterns might help.

For this scenario I recommend inserting the triggers, category and percentage as facts (Trigger) rather than hardcode them into rules. A small number of technical rules should then (1) associate Trigger facts with a NewsItem, (2) determine the category with the maximum for final classification (3) clean-up.

I think it would be a bad idea to have condition evaluation itself look into the text of a NewsItem to count key words. You might evaluate Trigger facts for the set of key words (once, after session startup and conserve it) and have one function to decompose a text, resulting in a frequency count of the "interesting" key words. Then, rules can match NewsItems and Triggers quite efficiently.